# How can I print custom message using Python argparse module

Tags: python, error-handling, argparse

I've got some code in Python using `argparse` module that checks if value is in range between 0 and 1

```
def check_if_in_range(string):
    value = float(string)
    if value < 0 or value > 1:
        raise parser.error('Value not in range between 0 and 1')
    return value

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('test', type=check_if_in_range)
parser.parse_args()
```

If I call it in terminal with e.g. 2, it's shows an error as expected:

```
usage: tests.py [-h] test
tests.py: error: Value not in range between 0 and 1
```

My question is, how can I print custom error message as one string - so when I call it with 2, it only prints string `Value not in range between 0 and 1`

Comment: instead of raising exception you can simply use print. If you want to be more specific then use logger.ERROR from logging module

Comment: So simple, thank you!

Comment: `parser.error('your message')` can be called after parsing.  It will display the `usage` along with your message.